# Python 3 For loop vs next() iterator

Tags: python

I'm learning Python 3 (my first language since BASIC), and I have a general question:

If I want to iterate over something, how do I determine if the best way is to use a For loop or a generator? They appear to be closely related.

Comment: Iterators are not exactly the same as generators

Comment: Use a for-loop if you can. It's simple, and it uses iterators behind the scenes.

Comment: As long as you are using `for ... in ...`, does it matter?

Comment: A generator doesn't exactly iterate.  You can iterate through a generator, but that still requires a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for-loop if you can. It's simple, and it uses iterators behind the scenes. One of the great things about python's iterator system is that you don't need to think about them most of the time. It is quite rare that you'll need to explicitly call `next()` on something.

This is kind of general, but so is your question. If you have a particular use case in mind, edit your question to add it and you'll get more detailed responses.

Comment: Great answer. No more specifics needed. Thank you!